# How can I mock the imports of an ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following ES6 modules:

#### File *network.js*

```
export function getDataFromServer() {
  return ...
}
```

#### File *widget.js*

```
import { getDataFromServer } from 'network.js';

export class Widget() {
  constructor() {
    getDataFromServer("dataForWidget")
    .then(data => this.render(data));
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to test Widget with a mock instance of `getDataFromServer`. If I used separate `<script>`s instead of ES6 modules, like in Karma, I could write my test like:

```
describe("widget", function() {
  it("should do stuff", function() {
    let getDataFromServer = spyOn(window, "getDataFromServer").andReturn("mockData")
    let widget = new Widget();
    expect(getDataFromServer).toHaveBeenCalledWith("dataForWidget");
    expect(otherStuff).toHaveHappened();
  });
});
```

However, if I'm testing ES6 modules individually outside of a browser (like with [Mocha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocha_(JavaScript_framework)) + [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler))), I would write something like:

```
import { Widget } from 'widget.js';

describe("widget", function() {
  it("should do stuff", function() {
    let getDataFromServer = spyOn(?????) // How to mock?
    .andReturn("mockData")
    let widget = new Widget();
    expect(getDataFromServer).toHaveBeenCalledWith("dataForWidget");
    expect(otherStuff).toHaveHappened();
  });
});
```

Okay, but now `getDataFromServer` is not available in `window` (well, there's no `window` at all), and I don't know a way to inject stuff directly into `widget.js`'s own scope.

### So where do I go from here?

1. **Is there a way to access the scope of `widget.js`, or at least replace its imports with my own code?**
2. **If not, how can I make `Widget` testable?**

---

### Stuff I considered:

#### a. Manual dependency injection.

Remove all imports from `widget.js` and expect the caller to provide the deps.

```
export class Widget() {
  constructor(deps) {
    deps.getDataFromServer("dataForWidget")
    .then(data => this.render(data));
  }
}
```

I'm very uncomfortable with messing up Widget's public interface like this and exposing implementation details. No go.

---

#### b. Expose the imports to allow mocking them.

Something like:

```
import { getDataFromServer } from 'network.js';

export let deps = {
  getDataFromServer
};

export class Widget() {
  constructor() {
    deps.getDataFromServer("dataForWidget")
    .then(data => this.render(data));
  }
}
```

then:

```
import { Widget, deps } from 'widget.js';

describe("widget", function() {
  it("should do stuff", function() {
    let getDataFromServer = spyOn(deps.getDataFromServer)  // !
      .andReturn("mockData");
    let widget = new Widget();
    expect(getDataFromServer).toHaveBeenCalledWith("dataForWidget");
    expect(otherStuff).toHaveHappened();
  });
});
```

This is less invasive, but it requires me to write a lot of boilerplate for each module, and there's still a risk of me using `getDataFromServer` instead of `deps.getDataFromServer` all the time. I'm uneasy about it, but that's my best idea so far.

Comment: If there is no _native_ mock support for this kind of import I would probably think over writing an own transformer for babel converting your ES6 style import to a custom mockable import system. This for sure would add another layer of possible failure and changes the code you want to test, ... .

Comment: I can't set a test suite right now, but I'd try to use jasmin's `createSpy` (https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/375a6f9fda57fdd896acce9abba7aca2e02b310a/src/core/base.js#L64) function with an imported reference to getDataFromServer from 'network.js' module. So that, in the widget's tests file you'd import getDataFromServer, and then would `let spy = createSpy('getDataFromServer', getDataFromServer)`

Comment: The second guess is to return an object from 'network.js' module, not a function. In that way, you could `spyOn` on that object, imported from `network.js` module. It's always a reference to the same object.

Comment: Actually, it's already an object, from what I can see: http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=import%20%7B%20funcName%20%7D%20from%20'module.js'%3B%0A%0AfuncName()%3B%0A%0Aexport%20function%20getDataFromServer()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%200%3B%0A%7D

Comment: Well, the main problem is with that approach you'd need to import the whole  `network` module (object) and make call like that: `network.getDataFromServer()`, not just `getDataFromServer()`. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock dependencies for unit tests with ES6 Modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323031/how-to-mock-dependencies-for-unit-tests-with-es6-modules)

Comment: I don't really understand how dependency injection messes up `Widget`'s public interface? `Widget` is messed up *without* `deps`. Why not make the dependency explicit?

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323031/how-to-mock-dependencies-for-unit-tests-with-es6-modules

Answer (score 146):

I've started employing the `import * as obj` style within my tests, which imports all exports from a module as properties of an object which can then be mocked. I find this to be a lot cleaner than using something like rewire or proxyquire or any similar technique. I've done this most often when needing to mock Redux actions, for example. Here's what I might use for your example above:

```
import * as network from 'network.js';

describe("widget", function() {
  it("should do stuff", function() {
    let getDataFromServer = spyOn(network, "getDataFromServer").andReturn("mockData")
    let widget = new Widget();
    expect(getDataFromServer).toHaveBeenCalledWith("dataForWidget");
    expect(otherStuff).toHaveHappened();
  });
});
```

If your function happens to be a default export, then `import * as network from './network'` would produce `{default: getDataFromServer}` and you can mock network.default.

**Note**: the ES spec defines modules as read-only, and many ES transpilers have started honoring this, which may break this style of spying. This is highly dependent on your transpiler as well as your test framework. For example, I think Jest performs some magic to make this work, though [Jasmine does not, at least currently](https://jasmine.github.io/pages/faq.html#module-spy). YMMV.

Comment: Do you use the `import * as obj` only in the test or also in your regular code?

Comment: I usually use this pattern only in my test- in my app code, I usually use `import { thing1, thing2 } from 'thinglib';`.

Comment: @carpeliam This wont work with the ES6 module spec where the imports are readonly.

Comment: Jasmine is complaining `[method_name] is not declared writable or has no setter` which makes sense since es6 imports are constant. Is there a way to workaround?

Comment: @lpan If you mean to say that es6 imports can not be reassigned, this is correct, but es6 constants don't protect from child modification, which is what spying ultimately does. All of this requires that your properties are writable though (which I think is what ashish is getting at in his comment above) - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7757337/242582.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one was really difficult for me to find! The import as made the trick

Comment: Thank you for posting this, @carpeliam. It is very helpful.
A question though, is there any way to imoprt the system under test multiple times, such as in a beforeEach block? The reason being tests can mess up state of the system under test for other tests that follow.

Comment: @Francisc `import` (unlike `require`, which can go anywhere) gets hoisted, so you can’t technically import multiple times. Sounds like your spy is being called elsewhere? In order to keep the tests from messing up state (known as test pollution), you can reset your spies in an afterEach (e.g. sinon.sandbox). Jasmine I believe does this automatically.

Comment: @carpeliam Thank you for your comment. I meant something like the fiddle I linked at the end. Without ability to reimport the system under test, it doesn't seem possible to test that because once the promise stored in `ready` settles, you can't change it. Am I wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/w9x3bp8r/2/

Comment: @carpeliam Here's another example I thought of https://jsfiddle.net/b93L16nz/. Code is for illustration as well. The non-exported `response` variable, once set, cannot be changed. So if I want to test both success and fail situations, I cannot without reimporting the system under test. I can add methods to allow me to achieve that, but I don't like changing implementation to accommodate unit tests generally.

Comment: when doing this 
`import * as network from 'network.js';`  then `network` object is frozen right ? so how does `spyOn(network, "getDataFromServer").andReturn("mockData")` modify the `getDataFromServer` method ?

Comment: @agent47 the object is not necessarily frozen - some modules will freeze their exports, but many will not. This is what ashish gets at in an above comment.

Comment: @carpeliam i read here http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_imports-as-views-on-exports (search for frozen object) that when importing with `*` the object is frozen by default (readonly), so is that not true ?

Comment: @agent47 The problem is that while the ES6 spec specifically prevents this answer from working, in exactly the way  you mentioned, most people who write `import` in their JS aren't really using ES6 modules. Something like webpack or babel will step in at build-time and convert it either into their own internal mechanism for calling distant parts of the code (eg `__webpack_require__`) or into one of the pre-ES6 *de facto* standards, CommonJS, AMD or UMD. And that conversion often doesn't adhere strictly to the spec. So for many, many devs just now, this answer works fine. For now.

Answer (score 39):

[carpeliam is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-can-i-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module/38414108#38414108), but note that if you want to spy on a function in a module and use another function in that module calling that function, you need to call that function as part of the exports namespace, otherwise the spy won't be used.

Wrong example:

```
// File mymodule.js

export function myfunc2() {return 2;}
export function myfunc1() {return myfunc2();}

// File tests.js
import * as mymodule

describe('tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(mymodule, 'myfunc2').and.returnValue = 3;
    });

    it('calls myfunc2', () => {
        let out = mymodule.myfunc1();
        // 'out' will still be 2
    });
});
```

Right example:

```
export function myfunc2() {return 2;}
export function myfunc1() {return exports.myfunc2();}

// File tests.js
import * as mymodule

describe('tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(mymodule, 'myfunc2').and.returnValue = 3;
    });

    it('calls myfunc2', () => {
        let out = mymodule.myfunc1();
        // 'out' will be 3, which is what you expect
    });
});
```

Comment: I wish i could up vote this answer 20 more times!  Thank you!

Comment: Can someone explain why this is the case? Is exports.myfunc2() a copy of myfunc2() without being a direct reference?

Comment: @ColinWhitmarsh `exports.myfunc2` is a direct reference to `myfunc2` until `spyOn` replaces it with a reference to a spy function.
`spyOn` will change the value of `exports.myfunc2` and replace it with a spy object, whereas `myfunc2` remains untouched in the module's scope (because `spyOn` has no access to it)

Comment: shouldn't importing with `*` freeze the object and the object attributes cannot be changed ?

Comment: Just a note that this recommendation of using `export function` along with `exports.myfunc2` is technically mixing commonjs and ES6 module syntax and this is not allowed in newer versions of webpack (2+) that require all-or-nothing ES6 module syntax usage.  I added an answer below based on this one that will work in ES6 strict environments.

Answer (score 9):

[vdloo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-can-i-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module/41426098#41426098) got me headed in the right direction, but using both [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) "exports" and ES6 module "export" keywords together in the same file did not work for me ([Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) v2 or later complains).

Instead, I'm using a default (named variable) export wrapping all of the individual named module exports and then importing the default export in my tests file.  I'm using the following export setup with [Mocha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocha_(JavaScript_framework))/Sinon and stubbing works fine without needing *rewire*, etc.:

```
// MyModule.js
let MyModule;

export function myfunc2() { return 2; }
export function myfunc1() { return MyModule.myfunc2(); }

export default MyModule = {
  myfunc1,
  myfunc2
}

// tests.js
import MyModule from './MyModule'

describe('MyModule', () => {
  const sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox.stub(MyModule, 'myfunc2').returns(4);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  it('myfunc1 is a proxy for myfunc2', () => {
    expect(MyModule.myfunc1()).to.eql(4);
  });
});
```

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks. Just wanted to mention that the `let MyModule` isn't required to use the default export (it can be a raw object). Also, this method doesn't require `myfunc1()` to call `myfunc2()`, it works to just spy on it directly.

Comment: @QuarkleMotion: It appears you edited this with a different account than your main account by accident.  That's why your edit had to go through a manual approval -- it didn't look like it was from *you*  I assume this was just an accident, but, if it was intentional, you should [read the official policy on sock puppet accounts so you don't accidentally violate the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange).

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler thanks for the heads up - this was a mistake, I did not intend to modify this answer with my work email-linked SO account.

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question! Where's widget.js and network.js? This answer seems to have no transitive dependency, which is what made the original question hard.

Answer (score 8):

I implemented a library that attempts to solve the issue of run time mocking of TypeScript class imports without needing the original class to know about any explicit dependency injection.

The library uses the `import * as` syntax and then replaces the original exported object with a stub class. It retains type safety so your tests will break at compile time if a method name has been updated without updating the corresponding test.

This library can be found here: [ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports).

Comment: This module needs more github stars

Answer (score 3):

I have found this syntax to be working:

My module:

```
// File mymod.js
import shortid from 'shortid';

const myfunc = () => shortid();
export default myfunc;
```

My module's test code:

```
// File mymod.test.js
import myfunc from './mymod';
import shortid from 'shortid';

jest.mock('shortid');

describe('mocks shortid', () => {
  it('works', () => {
    shortid.mockImplementation(() => 1);
    expect(myfunc()).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

See [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html).

Comment: +1 and with some additional instructions: Seems to only work with node modules i.e. stuff that you have on package.json. And more important is, something that is not mentioned in the Jest docs, the string passed to `jest.mock()` has to match the name used in import/packge.json instead of the name of constant. In the docs they are both same, but with code like `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'` you need setup the mock as `jest.mock('jsonwebtoken')`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but I think [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) might work. It allows you to substitute the real module with a mock that you have provided. Below is an example to give you an idea of how it works:

```
mockery.enable();
var networkMock = {
    getDataFromServer: function () { /* your mock code */ }
};
mockery.registerMock('network.js', networkMock);

import { Widget } from 'widget.js';
// This widget will have imported the `networkMock` instead of the real 'network.js'

mockery.deregisterMock('network.js');
mockery.disable();
```

It seems like `mockery` isn't maintained anymore and I think it only works with Node.js, but nonetheless, it's a neat solution for mocking modules that are otherwise hard to mock.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered [babel-plugin-mockable-imports](https://github.com/robertknight/babel-plugin-mockable-imports) which handles this problem neatly, IMHO. If you are already using [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(compiler)), it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

See suppose I'd like to mock results returned from `isDevMode()` function in order to check to see how code would behave under certain circumstances.

The following example is tested against the following setup

```
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.3",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
```

Here is an example of a simple test case scenario

```
import * as coreLobrary from '@angular/core';
import { urlBuilder } from '@app/util';

const isDevMode = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(true);

Object.defineProperty(coreLibrary, 'isDevMode', {
  value: isDevMode
});

describe('url builder', () => {
  it('should build url for prod', () => {
    isDevMode.and.returnValue(false);
    expect(urlBuilder.build('/api/users').toBe('https://api.acme.enterprise.com/users');
  });

  it('should build url for dev', () => {
    isDevMode.and.returnValue(true);
    expect(urlBuilder.build('/api/users').toBe('localhost:3000/api/users');
  });
});
```

Exemplified contents of `src/app/util/url-builder.ts`

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '@root/environments';

export function urlBuilder(urlPath: string): string {
  const base = isDevMode() ? environment.API_PROD_URI ? environment.API_LOCAL_URI;

  return new URL(urlPath, base).toJSON();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout)-based library [mock-import](https://github.com/coderaiser/mock-import) for this purpose.

Let's suppose you have a code you want to test, let it be `cat.js`:

```js
import {readFile} from 'fs/promises';

export default function cat() {
    const readme = await readFile('./README.md', 'utf8');
    return readme;
};
```

And [tap-based](https://github.com/coderaiser/supertape) test with a name `test.js` will look this way:

```js
import {test, stub} from 'supertape';
import {createImport} from 'mock-import';

const {mockImport, reImport, stopAll} = createMockImport(import.meta.url);

// check that stub called
test('cat: should call readFile', async (t) => {
    const readFile = stub();
    
    mockImport('fs/promises', {
        readFile,
    });
    
    const cat = await reImport('./cat.js');
    await cat();
    
    stopAll();
    
    t.calledWith(readFile, ['./README.md', 'utf8']);
    t.end();
});

// mock result of a stub
test('cat: should return readFile result', async (t) => {
    const readFile = stub().returns('hello');
    
    mockImport('fs/promises', {
        readFile,
    });
    
    const cat = await reImport('./cat.js');
    const result = await cat();
    
    stopAll();
    
    t.equal(result, 'hello');
    t.end();
});
```

To run test we should add [--loader](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_loaders) parameter:

```sh
node --loader mock-import test.js
```

Or use [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options):

```sh
NODE_OPTIONS="--loader mock-import" node test.js
```

On the bottom level `mock-import` uses [transformSource](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_transformsource_source_context_defaulttransformsource) hook, which replaces on the fly all `imports` with constants declaration to such form:

```js
const {readFile} = global.__mockImportCache.get('fs/promises');
```

So `mockImport` adds new entry into `Map` and `stopAll` clears all mocks, so tests not overlap.

All this stuff needed because [ESM has it's own separate cache](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_cache) and userland code has no direct access to it.

Comment: this one works for me

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding it to the class and then overwriting it, because this lib was not allowing me to do anything with their getter :'(

```
import { libFn } from 'lib';

class MyComponent {
  libFn = libFn;

  inUse() {
    this.libFn();
  }
}
```

```
it('', () => {
  component.libFn = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(5);
});
```

That's how easy it is. I'm pretty sure that's not the best way, because the libFn should not be part of my class. Jasmine should learn from Jest by mocking libs...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to mock an imported function

**File network.js**

```
export function exportedFunc(data) {
  //..
}
```

**File widget.js**

```
import { exportedFunc } from 'network.js';

export class Widget() {
  constructor() {
    exportedFunc("data")
  }
}
```

**Test file**

```
import { Widget } from 'widget.js';
import { exportedFunc } from 'network'
jest.mock('network', () => ({
  exportedFunc: jest.fn(),
}))

describe("widget", function() {
  it("should do stuff", function() {
    let widget = new Widget();
    expect(exportedFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Jest seem not yet ready for esm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71373579/unit-test-mock-node-17-typescript-esm-module#comment126160658_71373579

Answer (score 0):

<s>I haven't been able to try it out yet, but</s> (Live demo at codesandbox.io/s/adoring-orla-wqs3zl?file=/index.js)

If you have a browser-based test runner in theory you should be able to include a Service Worker that can intercept the request for the ES6 module you want to mock out and replace it with an alternative implementation (similar or the same as how [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/) approaches things)

So something like this in your service worker

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.url.includes("canvas-confetti")) {
      event.respondWith(
        new Response('const confetti=function() {}; export default confetti;', {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript' }
        })
      );
    }
});
```

If your source code is pulling in an ES6 module like this

```
import confetti from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti';
confetti();
```

Comment: This would only work if `getDataFromServer` is using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or importing from a URL, right? (not for WebSockets, dynamic `import` passed through [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/), etc.)

Comment: Yeah only stuff a service worker can intercept, so no websockets for sure. Dynamic import I'm guessing would still be fine though (or at least I can't think how that'd differ too much from the static case). Wish there was an easy way to try this in an online sandbox and link to it

Comment: Found out CodeSandbox lets you stick in a service worker in their Node server option. Made a demo with that of this concept here - https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-orla-wqs3zl?file=/index.js (I was finding unregistering the service worker between edits tough, so I just forked the sandbox each time for that...)