# Use jest.mock and TypeScript without cluttered type casting?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jestjs, typescript2.0

When I compile my a test using the TypeScript compiler and working with a Jest mock, I often receive errors from `tsc` like:

```
error TS2339: Property 'mockImplementationOnce' does not exist on type
              'typeof readFile'.
```

from this minimal test:

```
jest.mock('fs');
// Run before the imports but does not alter types :(

import { readFile } from 'fs';
import { fnThatReadsFile } from './lib';

it('should read a file', () => {
  const err = {};
  readFile.mockImplementationOnce((_, callback) => callback(err, null));
  // ^^ error TS2339: Property 'mockImplementationOnce' does not exist on type 'typeof readFile'.

  fnThatReadsFile();
  // expect...
});
```

What solutions are there other than:

- casting: `readFile as jest.Mock<{}>`
- [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

Could a TypeScript plugin perform the module augmentation when modules are required by `jest.mock`?

Comment: Maybe [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414108/6392661) that someone is using helps

Answer (score 9):

simplest solution is to import fs like this: `const fs = require('fs')`, and use `(fs.readFile as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce ...`

Comment: Thanks Herman. I've found that casting is the most verbose way to work since you need to cast it every time you're working with it.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is to import directly from the mock file. It looks inelegant, but works.

```
import { readFile } from '../__mocks__/fs';
```