# How to mock a import?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am working on a tdd project with Node.js and Typescript. I have a class named `HttpSample` which is imported to another class named `Sample` as follows.

```
import {HttpSample} from "./httpService"

...

const http: HttpSample = new HttpSample();
http.get();
```

How can I mock the `HttpSample` class inside the `Sample`'s test file?

**Update**

I am using `Jasmine` and `mocha` frameworks

Comment: what testing framework are you using? they should have the concept of stubs / mocks?

Comment: I am using Jasmine & mocha

Comment: think this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-to-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module

Comment: @lustoykov this is for JavaScript I want a solution for TypeScript

Comment: Anything working in Javascript will work in Typescript as well

Comment: Imports can be mocked on non-native modules. Where is `const http: HttpSample` located? Is it in function scope? Please, update the code, `...` is not specific enough, the solution depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports) is a library that is designed to fix this issue in Typescript while remaining type safe. It's built on top of sinon instead of Jasmine but will play nice with both.

In `sample.spec.ts`

```
import * as httpSample from './httpService';
import { ImportMock } from 'ts-mock-imports';
import { Sample } from './sample';

const httpMock = ImportMock.mockClass(httpSample, 'HttpSample');

// Sample will now get a mock version of HttpSample
const sample = new Sample();
```