# How can the rxjs 6 webSocket function be mocked for unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, websocket, jasmine, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to unit test some code that uses the `webSocket` function from rxjs6.  I have tried to spy on the webSocket function by doing the following (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-to-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module)): -

`import * as rxJsWebSocket from 'rxjs/webSocket';`

```
subject = new Subject();
webSocketSpy = spyOn(rxJsWebSocket, 'webSocket').and.returnValue(<any>subject);
```

but I got the error: -

`Error: <spyOn> : webSocket is not declared writable or has no setter`

Is there any other way to achieve this or is there a workaround for the error?

I've also tried [ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports) with no success.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me using `"rxjs": "^6.6.3"`. E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

export function main() {
  return webSocket('ws://localhost:8081');
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import * as rxJsWebSocket from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';

describe('55415481', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const subject = new Subject();
    const webSocketSpy = spyOn(rxJsWebSocket, 'webSocket').and.returnValue(<any>subject);
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toBe(<any>subject);
    expect(webSocketSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ws://localhost:8081');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
Executing 1 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 21376)

Test Suites & Specs:
(node:74151) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

1. 55415481
   ✔ should pass (8ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   1 of 1
Expects: 2 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.02 seconds
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/55415481