# unit test mock - node 17 + typescript + ESM module

Tags: jestjs, mocking, sinon, es6-modules

There is a simple question I cannot find an answer to.
When using:

1. Node 17 + Typescript
2. ESM ("type": "module" in package.json)

**Can I implement mock** for one function only? or module?

If so, can I get an example?
No matter what framework you use.

thanks!!

package.json:

```json
{
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules  ./node_modules/.bin/jest --bail --colors --coverage --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --verbose",

    "jest": {
        "preset": "ts-jest/presets/default-esm",
        "transform": {
            ".ts": "ts-jest"
        },
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "js",
            "json"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
        ],
        "globals": {
            "ts-jest": {
                "useESM": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jest.spy gives me an error: cannot assign to read-only property I tried using Sinon too, and I got: es modules cannot be stubbed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Developments in ESM support in jest is blocked due to 2 bugs in v8 and chromium. This is a real frustration because 1000s of projects are blocked from migrating to the esm. You can read about it here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430#issuecomment-1055787154

Comment: Plus you may find this thread interesting https://stackoverflow.com/q/35240469/3370568

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `vitest`.

I just tried many options like uvu and esmock. Nothing worked. `vitest` had appropriate documentation and worked out of the box. Can mock functions from different ESM modules, and at any time (hoisting). It just works.

At the beginning I didn't want to use a product from a commercial project. But all of the other options just work.

`vitest` syntax is exactly the same as in jest.

```js
import { ALL_EMB_TYPES } from "./db.js"

vi.mock("./db.js", async () => {
  let actual = await vi.importActual("./db.js") as any
  return {
    ...actual,
    store: vi.fn(),
  }
})

// ALL_EMB_TYPES retained from original implementation
// store mocked
```