# Unit test gives an error about missing provide AngularFireModule in my AppModule

Tags: angular, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I created a project based on angular with the addition of firebase, when performing unit testing, karma shows an error from all components to which services containing Firestore functionality are attached

here is the error itself:

```
ProductComponent > should create
Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).
    at getSchedulers (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:154:15)
    at runOutsideAngular (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:160:12)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:227:21
    at new ProductService (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/shared/services/product/product.service.ts:22:40)
    at Object.factory (ng:///ProductService/ɵfac.js:4:10)
    at callback (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:9412:43)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:694:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:9411:17)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:9281:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13949:36)
```

The error itself says that the AngularFireModule (in my case provideFirebaseApp) is either not provided in my NgModule, or is provided outside my NgModule, although there is no such thing, and all services are transferred to my NgModule, here is the NgModule file itself:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CabinetComponent } from './cabinet/cabinet.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './pages/product/product.component';
import { ZrobySamComponent } from './pages/zroby-sam/zroby-sam.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { AdminCategoryComponent } from './admin/admin-category/admin-category.component';
import { AdminProductComponent } from './admin/admin-product/admin-product.component';
import { MainComponent } from './cabinet/main/main.component';
import { IMaskModule } from 'angular-imask';

import { NgbAlertModule, NgbModule, NgbPaginationModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
import { register } from 'swiper/element';
import { DeliveryComponent } from './components/delivery/delivery.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CabinetModule } from './cabinet/cabinet.module';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './auth/register/register.component';
import { AdminAuthComponent } from './auth/admin-auth/admin-auth.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FirebaseAppModule, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, AuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
// import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideStorage, getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { DostavkaComponent } from './pages/dostavka/dostavka.component';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductInfoComponent } from './pages/product/product-info/product-info.component';
import { ProductModule } from './pages/product/product.module';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './pages/check-out/check-out.component';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { PassSucefullComponent } from './pages/pass-sucefull/pass-sucefull.component';
import { CategoryService } from './shared/services/category/category.service';
import { ProductService } from './shared/services/product/product.service';
import { IngrService } from './shared/services/ingr/ingr.service';
import { AuthService } from './shared/services/auth/auth.service';
import { OrdersService } from './shared/services/orders/orders.service';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

register();
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,
    CabinetComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ZrobySamComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MainComponent,
    DeliveryComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    DostavkaComponent,
    CheckOutComponent,
    PassSucefullComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AdminAuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    IMaskModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbPaginationModule,
    NgbAlertModule,
    CabinetModule,
    AdminModule,
    ProductModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AuthModule,
    SharedModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  providers: [
    CategoryService,
    ProductService,
    IngrService,
    AuthService,
    OrdersService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And also here is the ProductService file to which the error description refers here>
at new ProductService (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/shared/services/product/product.service.ts:23:40):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Firestore,
  CollectionReference,
  addDoc,
  collectionData,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
  deleteDoc, docData, collection
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { IProductRequire } from '../../interface/product/product.interfaces';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productCollection
  private reviewCollection
  constructor(
    private afs: Firestore
  ){
    this.productCollection = collection(this.afs , 'products')
    this.reviewCollection = collection(this.afs , 'reviews')
  }
  public productSub!: any
  get(){
    return collectionData(this.productCollection, {idField: 'id'})
  }


  getById(id: string){
    const productDocumentReference = doc(this.afs,  `products/${id}`)
    return docData(productDocumentReference, {idField: 'id'})
  }

  create(product: IProductRequire){
    return addDoc(this.productCollection, product)

  }

  update(product: IProductRequire, id: string){
    const productDocumentReference = doc(this.afs,  `products/${id}`)
    return updateDoc(productDocumentReference, {...product})
  }

  delete(id: string){
    const productDocumentReference = doc(this.afs,  `products/${id}`)
    return deleteDoc(productDocumentReference)
  }

  resolve(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const productDocumentReference = doc(this.afs,  `products/${activatedRouteSnapshot.paramMap.get('id')}`)
    return docData(productDocumentReference, {idField: 'id'})
  }

  addReview(review: any){
    return addDoc(this.reviewCollection, review)
  }

}
```

and the ProductCompoennt file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from 'src/app/auth/auth.component';
import { IUpdate } from 'src/app/shared/interface/auth/auth.interfaces';
import { ICategoryResponse } from 'src/app/shared/interface/category/categories.interfaces';
import { IProductResponse } from 'src/app/shared/interface/product/product.interfaces';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/shared/services/auth/auth.service';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/shared/services/category/category.service';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/shared/services/product/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.scss']
})
export class ProductComponent {
  public eventSubscription
  constructor(
    private data: ProductService,
    private ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private categroyData: CategoryService,
    private userData: AuthService,
    private dialog: MatDialog

  ) {
    this.eventSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.category = this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('category') as string;
        this.getData()
        this.getUser()


      }
    })
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.category = this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('category') as string;

    this.getData()
    this.getUser()
  }



  public categorySelect!: string

  public categoryList!: ICategoryResponse[]
  public category!: string
  public products!: IProductResponse[]
  getData() {
    this.category = this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('category') as string;

    this.data.get().subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data.filter(product => product["category"] === `${this.category}`) as Array<IProductResponse>

    })
    this.categroyData.getCategories()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.categoryList = data.sort(function (a, b) {
          return a["order"] - b["order"]

        }) as ICategoryResponse[]


      })
      
  }



  Count(product: IProductResponse, value: boolean) {
    if (!value && product.count > 1) {
      product.count--
    }
    if (value && product.count < 999) {
      product.count++
    }
  }
  public busket: IProductResponse[] = []
  addToBuscket(product: IProductResponse) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('basket') != 'null') {
      this.busket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket') as string)
      if (this.busket?.some(prod => prod.id === product.id)) {
        const index = this.busket.findIndex(prod => prod.id === product.id);
        this.busket[index].count += product.count;
      } else {
        this.busket?.push(product)
        console.log(product)

      }
    } else {
      this.busket.push(product);

    }

    localStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(this.busket));
    product.count = 1;

  }
  public testUser: string = ''
  public user!: IUpdate
  getUser() {
    this.testUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser') as string
    if (this.testUser != '' && this.testUser != null) {
      this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') as string)
    }
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(AuthComponent, {
      panelClass: 'auth-dialog'
    })
  }

  addFavorite(product: IProductResponse) {
    if (this.testUser != '' && this.testUser != null) {
      if (this.user.favorite.length != 0) {
        if (this.user.favorite.some(prod => prod.id === product.id)) {
          let index = this.user.favorite.indexOf(product)
          this.user.favorite.splice(index, 1)
        } else {
          this.user.favorite.push(product)

        }
      } else {
        this.user.favorite.push(product)


      }
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.user))
      this.userData.change(this.user, this.user.uid)
      this.getFavorite(product)
    } else {
      this.openDialog()
    }
  }


  getFavorite(product: IProductResponse) {
    if (this.testUser != '' && this.testUser != null) {
      if (this.user.favorite.some(prod => prod.id === product.id)) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } else {
      return false
    }

  }

  fastOrder(product: IProductResponse) {
    this.addToBuscket(product)
    this.router.navigate(['/check-out'])

  }




  setCategorySelect() {
    let select = document.querySelector('.select-cat') as HTMLSelectElement
    let value = select.value
    this.router.navigate(['/product/' + value])
  }
}
```

here is the spec.ts file ProductService:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { Storage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

describe('ProductService', () => {
  let service: ProductService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: Storage, useValue: {}},
        {provide: Auth, useValue: {}},
        {provide: Firestore, useValue: {}},
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ProductService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and spec.ts file ProductComponent:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';

describe('ProductComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProductComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: Storage, useValue: {}},
        {provide: Auth, useValue: {}},
        {provide: Firestore, useValue: {}},
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

also additional materials: package.json :

```
{
  "name": "tomatina",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@firebase/webchannel-wrapper": "^0.10.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "angular-imask": "^7.1.3",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "dateformat": "^5.0.3",
    "imask": "^7.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "swiper": "^10.2.0",
    "tslib": "2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

I checked all the providers in the AppModule file, as well as the service file itself, but at first glance everything should work, and I don’t understand the reason for not passing this test

Answer (score 0):

The error that you see makes sense since your component is using:

```
import {
  Firestore,
  CollectionReference,
  addDoc,
  collectionData,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
  deleteDoc, docData, collection
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
```

but you are only mocking `Firestore`.

Even though these are not modules/components, they are still elements of the `"@angular/fire/firestore"`.

You need to provide mocks for these as well, otherwise they will rely on the actual package, which is the source of your error.

Will also leave this stackoverflow: [How can I mock the imports of an ES6 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-can-i-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module), since you may have issues on how to mock those elements.