# Flow: Mutation of module exports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have a module which exports a function:

```
// module.js

export function doSomething() {
  // ...
}
```

I need to mock this function in tests. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40486695/1318939), I can do the following:

```
// module.test.js

import * as module from './module';

it('does something', () => {
    module.doSomething = jest.fn(() => console.log('Something was done'))

    // test
})
```

This code works (the function implementation is being replaced), but Flow is unhappy: `Error:(101, 3) Flow: assignment of property 'doSomething'. Mutation not allowed on exports of "./module"`

I can't seem to find any information about this particular error (both Google and Stack Overflow search give me exactly 0 results).

Are these complaints justified or can I just ignore them?

If it's the latter, what's the way to explain to Flow that this is nothing to worry about (other than using `// $FlowExpectedError` in every case)?

Comment: As the answer you linked to says, `solve this by using a hack`. You're now seeing why this is a hack. Reassigning an export from outside the module is not allowed by ES6. It does work with Babel 6 though.

Comment: ^ This. Btw, Jest provides a way to mock CJS modules (which are likely used under the hood for ES6 module implementation).

Comment: okay, fair enough. I guess I'll have to find another way.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Alexandre no, I just accepted the fact that Flow is not quite mature yet and moved on.