# how to mock module when using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm using Jest for unit test in a vuejs2 project but got stuck in mocking [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/), a library imported in my component.

Suppose I have a component named `Player.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="player">
    <button class="player-button" @click="play">Player</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Howl } from 'howler';

export default {
  name: 'audioplayer',
  methods: {
    play() {
      console.log('player button clicked');
      new Howl({
        src: [ 'whatever.wav' ],
      }).play();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

then I have its test file named `Player.spec.js`. Test code was written based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465435/6279569), but the test failed since `called` wasn't set as true. It seems that mocked constructor won't be called when running this test.

```
import Player from './Player';
import Vue from 'vue';

describe('Player', () => {
  let called = false;

  jest.mock('howler', () => ({
    Howl({ src }) {
      this.play = () => {
        called = true;
        console.log(`playing ${src[0]} now`);
      };
    },
  }));

  test('should work', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Player);
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount();
    vm.$el.querySelector('.player-button').click();
    expect(called).toBeTruthy(); // => will fail
  })
})
```

Though I'm using Vuejs here, I considered it as a more general question related to the usage of Jest's `mock` API, but I'm not able to get further.

Answer (score 1):

The SO you linked to only works for react components. Here is a way to mock the module with a spy on the play function that can be tested with `toBeHaveCalled`

```
//import the mocked module
import { Howl } from 'howler'; 
// mock the module so it returns an object with the spy
jest.mock('howler', () => ({Howl: jest.fn()}));

const HowlMock ={play: jest.fn()}
// set the actual implementation of the spy so it returns the object with the play function
Howl.mockImplementation(()=> HowlMock)

describe('Player', () => {
  test('should work', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Player);
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount();
    vm.$el.querySelector('.player-button').click();
    expect(Howl).toBeHaveCalledWith({src:[ 'whatever.wav' ]})
    expect(HowlMock.play).toBeHaveCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: This solution seems promising to me, but I got `TypeError: _howler.Howl.mockImplementation is not a function`..

Comment: Mhmm, what do you get when logging `Howl`

Comment: `[Function: Howl]`

Comment: mockImplementation doesn't exist