# Mock import/module with Jest in React application

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on a React application and I want to test one module, let's call it B, that depends on another module, let's call it A.

The scenario could be something like this:

### moduleA.js

```
export function helperFn() {
  return { prop1: 10, prop2: 20 };
}
```

### moduleB.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { helperFn } from '../moduleA';

export class CustomComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const helperObj = helperFn();
    return (
      <div>{helperObj.prop1}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

The core libraries to test my components are Jest and Enzyme. My goal here is to test module B, but I want to test it in isolation and so I want to mock the dependency on moduleA.js.

I know one way would be to inject the helperFn as a prop instead of importing it so during the test I can inject a mock function, but there are modules quite big on this app that have a few dependencies each of them.

Researching a bit I found it is posible to mock a dependecy using Jest, but I tried many things with no success. I tried approaches from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest), also from [this post](http://madole.xyz/mocking-relative-dependencies-in-jest-with-jest-mock/) and I have no luck. I also read the [Manual Mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) and [Mock Functions](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html) guides from Jest docs, but I think they are pretty confusing.

I could make it work (i.e. I could mock moduleA.js dependency) using the approach on [this post](https://www.jamestease.co.uk/blether/mock-es6-imports-with-jest), but I had another problem then. It worked just fine to test moduleB.js, but when I went ahead and test moduleA.js, I had to import moduleA.js in moduleA.test.js and I got the mock while I wanted the real module.

So, I need help to understand how I can mock dependency A in moduleB test file.

I hope I was clear if not let me know and I will add the clarifications you might need.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed you can use `jest` to mock your dependency. There is some configuration you need to set in order to make it work with `import`. E.g. configuring `babel-jest`.

If you already have that configuration then you can mock it like so.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { helperFn } from '../moduleA';
jest.mock('../moduleA');

describe("CustomComp", () => {
  it("should render component", () => {
    helperFn.mockReturnValueOnce({
      prop1: "dummy"
    });
    const component = shallow(<CustomComp />);
  });
```

You can see a working example [here](https://github.com/BingoDelivery/requests-mobile-client/tree/master/components/request_delivery).

Comment: Thanks man, I tried a few things as I explain in my question and they did not work but this did work.

Comment: link is broken, can you fix please

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vue2 and trying to write tests for a Vue component. The Vue component uses a lot of other components that aren't really needed to test.

So for that reason, I created a mock for importing other components like below

```
jest.mock('@/core/components/UserInput.vue', () => ({
    exec: jest.fn(),
}));
```