# jest mock setup with fetch-mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

I am not sure why but the test fails as it says `Expected mock function to have been called.`. How should I setup the `addFundingSource` mock to have it called? I can't `jest.mock` the whole module like the others (for instance `jest.mock('../../../../_helpers/alerts');`) since the rest of the functions are also used from that module.

fetchFundingSource.js

```
export const addFundingSource = () => {
  ...
}

export const fetchFundingSource = (history, onNewPaymentClose) => {
  let config = {
    ....
  };

  return async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchFundingSourceRequest());

  try {
    const response = await fetch(fundingSourceEndpoint, config);
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) {
      showErrorAlert(jsonResponse);
      dispatch(fetchFundingSourceError(jsonResponse));

      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }

    dispatch(fetchFundingSourceSuccess(jsonResponse.count, jsonResponse.results));
    addFoundingSource(jsonResponse.results, history, onNewPaymentClose);
  } catch (error) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      console.log('Request failed', error);
    }
  }
};
```

test

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as fundingSource from '../../../../dashboard/global/ducks/fetchFundingSource';
import { fundingSourceEndpoint } from '../../../../_api/companyHelpers';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

jest.mock('../../../../_api/companyHelpers');
jest.mock('../../../../_helpers/alerts');
jest.mock('../../../../_api/authHelpers');

const middlewares = [thunk];
const createMockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('fetchFundingSource', () => {
  beforeEach(() => { fetch.resetMocks(); });
  const history = createMemoryHistory('/dashboard');
  const onNewPaymentClose = {};
  fundingSource.addFundingSource = jest.fn(); //Mock setup.

  it('dispatches the correct actions on successful fetch request', () => {
    const store = createMockStore({});
    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ count, results }));

    const expectedActions = [
      fetchFundingSourceRequestObject,
      fetchFundingSourceSuccessObject
    ];

    return store.dispatch(fundingSource.fetchFundingSource(history, onNewPaymentClose))
      .then(() => {
        expect(fundingSource.addFundingSource).toBeCalled(); //THIS FAILS
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example I can't see where the named export `addFundingSource` is actually mocked. You might intercept and mock the export like this:

```
import * as fundingSourceReduce from '../fetchFundingSource';
fundingSourceReduce.addFundingSource = jest.fn();
```

More examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest/45642837#45642837).

Please note that in order to ensure that mocks are set up with the right timing, they should be declared into `beforeEach` or directly into test's `it` call.

Comment: This is a good tip as it only mocks that one function from the module and it doesn't change the others. But for some reason it doesn't work. I updated my question accordingly. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: See prev comment too. I forgot to mention that the function seems to be mocked when I console log it in the test setup, still it calls the original function. Could it be because of the async fetch call?

Comment: Please note that in order to ensure that mocks are set up with the right timing, they should be declared into beforeEach or directly into test's it call.

Comment: It's still the same :(