# Instructing jest to use mock

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a basic app based on stock `create-react-app`, meaning its `jest` configuration is default as well. My folder structure is as follows:

```
src
└── __mocks__
    └── Item.js
└── __tests__
    └── Item.test.js
    └── List.test.js
└── Item.js
└── List.js
```

My mock is rather simple - I'm retrieving the original component that is wrapped within `react-dnd` context:

**../__mocks__/Item.js**

```
import Item from "../Item"

export default Item.DecoratedComponent
```

In my **Item.test.js**, if I import from the `__mocks__` folder directly, my tests run just fine:

```
import Item from '../__mocks__/Item'
```

However, I would like to instead instruct `jest` to use the mocked version of this module, something like this:

```
import Item from '../Item'
jest.mock('../Item')
```

The reason I want to do this is because when I write tests for the `List` component, which internally renders a number of `Item` components, I will not be importing the `Item` components directly in the `List.test.js`, but instead I would like to also instruct `jest` to use the mocked `Item` module.

The above, however, doesn't work for me, i.e. my tests seem to be using the original `Item` component, although [there are suggestions that this should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230046/2131598).

What am I doing wrong? How do I instruct `jest` correctly to use the mocked instance of the module?