# How to mock the api call in jest for saga test

Tags: jestjs, redux-saga

I am writing tests to test my saga.  Can anyone guide me how I can change the code below so that I can mock the api call?  I don`t want to test real data.

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { API_BUTTON_CLICK_SUCCESS, } from './actions/consts';
import { getDataFromAPI } from './api';

it('apiSideEffect - fetches data from API and dispatches a success action', () => {
  const generator = apiSideEffect();

  expect(generator.next().value)
    .toEqual(call(getDataFromAPI));

  expect(generator.next().value)
    .toEqual(put({ type: API_BUTTON_CLICK_SUCCESS }));

  expect(generator.next())
    .toEqual({ done: true, value: undefined });
});
```

The getDataFromAPI()

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getDataFromAPI =(
  method: string,
  url: string,
  path: string,
  data?: any
) =>{
  switch (method) {
    case "create": {
      return axios
        .post(url + path, data, {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json"
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          throw error.response;
        });
    }
```

I have tried to use

```
jest.mock('../../src/Utilities/api');
const { callApi } = require('../../src/Utilities/api');


callApi.mockImplementation( () => console.log("some api call"));
```

I am having the error

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/Payments/PaymentSagas.spec.ts:10:17)
>       at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>   at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
>       at <anonymous>
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
> ```

Comment: If you came up with a different solution please, let us know, otherwise accept my answer. Both could be useful for other users looking for the same answer 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I usually do

```
import * as apis from '../../src/Utilities/api';
jest.spyOn(api, "callApi");
api.callApi.mockImplementation(/* your mock */);
```

easily exportable as a per-se function

```
export function spyUtil(obj, name, mockFunction = undefined) {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(obj, name);
  let mock;
  if (mockFunction) {
    mock = jest.fn(mockFunction);
    obj[name].mockImplementation(mock);
  }
  return { spy, mock };
}
```

and consumable, in your test

```
spyUtil(apis, "callApi", jest.fn())
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not understood the example.  Do you have a GitHub or codepen example

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest)