# Jest - mock function, that is imported from another file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

The tested file uses a function that is imported from another file

```
import {myFunc} from './myFile'
```

How can I mock return value for this function in my tests for this file? I'm using jest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mock an ES6 module import using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what worked for me, I'm not sure if it's a good practice tho:

```
 import * as myFile from "./myFile";
 jest.mock("./myFile");
 myFile.myFunc = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
     return "Some Value";
 });
```

Comment: `jest.spyOn(myFile, 'myFunc').mockReturnValue('Some Value');` looks a bit nicer

Comment: Cannot do that with a `const`.