# Test Firebase authenticate Using Google Sign-In in jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I cannot figure out how to jest mock firebase authentication with google login properly.I have the following code:

**simple.tsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class simple extends Component {

  signInWithgoogle() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    // how to mock provider when simulate click event.
    firebaseApp.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.signInWithgoogle.bind(this)}>
          Login with Google
        </button>
      </div>

    );
  }
export default withRouter(connect(
)(simple));
```

**simple.test.tsx**

```
const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
const store = mockStore();

describe('<simple />', () => {
    test("simulate click button", () =>{
        const withProvider = (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <simple.WrappedComponent {...FirebaseAuthProps} />
            </Provider>
        );

        const wrapper = mount(withProvider);
        wrapper.find('Button').simulate('click');
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated with examples?

Comment: Can you tell me how you are importing firebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest

Comment: Here is i imported from firebase : `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`.

Comment: I have read official doc [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#before_you_begin) but i can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you sharing your test code? Is there any error?

Comment: I updated and edited about the test code. Please review it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript namespace is some kind of a JS function after compiling and type erasure. After knowing this, of course, you can assign properties to JS function. Here is the solution:

`simple.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class simple extends Component {
  signInWithgoogle() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.signInWithgoogle.bind(this)}>Login with Google</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(simple as any);
```

`simple.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import simple from './simple';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
const store = mockStore();
const FirebaseAuthProps = {};

jest.mock('firebase', () => {
  const auth = jest.fn();
  const mAuth = { signInWithRedirect: jest.fn() };
  // @ts-ignore
  auth.GoogleAuthProvider = jest.fn();
  // @ts-ignore
  auth.Auth = jest.fn(() => mAuth);
  return { auth };
});

describe('<simple />', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('simulate click button', () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    firebase.auth.mockImplementation(() => new firebase.auth.Auth());
    const withProvider = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <simple.WrappedComponent {...FirebaseAuthProps} />
      </Provider>
    );

    const wrapper = mount(withProvider);
    expect(wrapper.find('button').text()).toBe('Login with Google');
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(firebase.auth).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58554920/simple.spec.tsx (15.341s)
  <simple />
    ✓ simulate click button (82ms)

------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 simple.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        17.245s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58554920

Comment: FYI: I used `jest.clearAllMocks()` instead of `jest.resetAllMocks()` otherwise it kept returning `undefined` for my mocks.

Answer (score 2):

I also have a similar solution, if you decide to use Firebase Auth with Firebase Analytics:

```js
jest.mock('firebase/app', () => {
  const analytics = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    logEvent: jest.fn(),
  });

  const auth: any = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    signInWithRedirect: jest.fn(),
    getRedirectResult: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      credential: {
        providerId: 'Google',
      },
      user: {
        getIdToken: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('abc1234'),
      },
      additionalUserInfo: {
        profile: {
          email: 'test@test.com',
          name: 'John Doe',
        },
      },
    }),
  });

  auth.GoogleAuthProvider = class {
    addScope = jest.fn();
  };

  return { auth, analytics };
});
```