# How to use jest.mock in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Is there a way to use `jest.mock`'s in React? For example, say I want to re-use a component (e.g. Storybook) but want to mock an import / implementation detail for that original React component. Is this possible, and if so, how? Thanks!

**sampleComponent.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import sampleFn from './sampleFn';

const SampleComponent = () => <h1>{sampleFn()}</h1>; // expected output: 'Hello World'

export default SampleComponent;
```

**sampleMockComponent.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import SampleMockComponent from './sampleComponent';

jest.mock('./sampleFn');

const SampleMockComponent = () => <SampleComponent />; // expected output: 'Testing Mock'
```

**sampleFn.js:**

```
export default () => 'Hello World';
```

**__mocks__/sampleFn.js:**

```
export default () => 'Testing Mock';
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642837/1880431

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock for reasons that are not for testing.
I would not suggest you use jest mocks.

Go for a dependency injection pattern.

```
import React from 'react';
import sampleFn from './sampleFn';

// Unless sample is supplied, sampleFn will be used by default
const SampleComponent = () => {
  const { sample = sampleFn } = props;

  return <h1>{sample()}</h1>;
}

export default SampleComponent;
```