# React Enzyme - modify internals of shallow rendered functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I have a functional react component and I want to change a property value inside the component in an enzyme unit test (in my case the `ready` attribute). The unit test should use `shallow` to avoid rendering any children components.

Here is the simplified component code:

```js
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
// ...

const MyComponent: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {

  const {t, ready} = useTranslation('my-translation-namespace');
  // ...

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {ready &&
        <div className="my-component">some more content...</div>
      }
    </React.Fragment>)
};
export default MyComponent;
```

And this is the corresponding test:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {

  let component: ShallowWrapper;

  it('should be displayed', () => {
    component = shallow(<MyComponent/>);

    // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SET: component.ready = true

    expect(component.find('.my-component').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Any idea how to change the `ready` attribute to true in my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by mocking the `react-i18next` module with jest.

```js
const mockT = jest.fn((a) => a)
const mockReady = true
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => 
  jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: mockT, ready: mockReady })
  }))
);
```

Take a look at [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) or [this article](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) if you are using ES modules or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest) for other options.

edit: use [module factory](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) for second param of `jest.mock` instead if passing a plain object.

Comment: second parameter of mock is a function not object.

Comment: You are correct. I RTFM and updated my answer. Thanks!