# Jest check if function was called

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test some utility functions.

my_util.js:

```
export function myFunc(i) {
  if (i === 1){
    anotherFunc();
  }
}
```

another_util.js:

```
export function anotherFunc(i) {
    console.log('in anotherFunc');
}
```

What is the simplest way to test that `anotherFunc()` was called?  Here is my current unit test, which is failing. Is there a way to test that a function was called by it's name?

```
import { myFunc } from './my_util.js'

...

  it('myFunc should call anotherFunc', () => {
    const anotherFunc = jest.fn();
    myFunc(1);
    expect(anotherFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();  
  });
```

Results:

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Comment: Where is `anotherFunc` defined (in the normal code)?

Comment: `anotherFunc` is defined in a seperate .js file. I've updated the post to show this.

Comment: Please share _how_ it is imported? Or is it available globally?

Comment: Have added the export and import details

Comment: Yes, thank you. This answer here works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465435/8282103

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should just inject `anotherFunc` to `myFunc` as argument, it will make testing easier:

```js
function myFunc(i, cb) {
  if (i === 1){
    cb();
  }
}
```

```js
  it('myFunc should call anotherFunc', () => {
    const anotherFunc = jest.fn();
    myFunc(1, anotherFunc);
    expect(anotherFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();  
  });
```