# Vue.js 3: Vue is not defined with mount when running unit tests with external library

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am currently experienced the following error when running my unit tests:

```
ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

> 10 | import hljsVuePlugin from '@highlightjs/vue-plugin';
     | ^
```

Here is my component code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <highlightjs autodetect :code="'hello world'" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import hljsVuePlugin from '@highlightjs/vue-plugin';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    highlightjs: hljsVuePlugin.component,
  },
});
</script>
```

in my test file, I'm simply trying to mount this component:

```
const wrapper = mount(FooBlah, {
  global: {
    stubs: {
      highlightjs: {
        template: '<div />',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here are my libraries versions:

```
"vue": "^3.2.33",
"@highlightjs/vue-plugin": "^2.1.2",
"highlight.js": "^11.6.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.4",
"@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.2",
"@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0",
```

Is there any way I could tell him to simply ignore the `highlightjs` the component in the `jest.config` ?

Comment: what's the version of `@highlightjs/vue-plugin`?

Comment: I've just updated it :)

Comment: Did you register it correctly in main.js?

Comment: You need to mock most if not all third-party libs as you're not testing them but they have undetermined impact on your code.

Comment: @EstusFlask Is there an easy way to do it, I tried using the stubs parameter but it doesn"t seem to work

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim
I did yep, it works fine if I run the projet, it only fails with the tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, this fixed my issue:

```
jest.mock('@highlightjs/vue-plugin', () => ({
  hljsVuePlugin: {
    component: jest.fn(),
  },
}));
const wrapper = mount(FooBlah, {
  global: {
    stubs: {
      highlightjs: {
        template: '<div />',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

You can find more information here: [How can I mock an ES6 module import using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465047/how-can-i-mock-an-es6-module-import-using-jest)