# How to unit test mapDispatchToProps with thunk action

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, sinon, redux-thunk

I have the following Redux action creator:

```
export const keyDown = key => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { modifier } = getState().data;
    dispatch({ type: KEYDOWN, key });
    return handle(modifier, key); // Returns true or false
};
```

And the following connected component:

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onKeyDown: e => {
        if(e.target.tagName === "INPUT") return;
        const handledKey = dispatch(keyDown(e.keyCode));
        if(handledKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to write a test to ensure that `dispatch` is called with the `keyDown` action when the `tagName` is anything other than `"INPUT"`. This is my test:

```
import { spy } from "sinon";
import keycode from "keycodes";
import { mapDispatchToProps } from "./connected-component";
import { keyDown } from "./actions";

// Creates a simple Event stub...
const createEvent = (tag, keyCode) => ({
    target: {
        tagName: tag.toUpperCase()
    },
    preventDefault: spy(),
    keyCode
});

it("Dispatches a keyDown event with the specified keyCode if the selected element is not an <input>", () => {
    const dispatch = spy();
    const keyCode = keycode("u");
    mapDispatchToProps(dispatch).onKeyDown(createEvent("div", keyCode));
    // This fails...
    expect(dispatch).to.have.been.calledWith(keyDown(keycode));
});
```

Presumably this is something to do with using arrow functions? Is there any way I can ensure that dispatch was called with the function signature that I expect?

Comment: So are you testing that string equality and the return statement works, or that a developer didn't accidentally remove it? God I dislike most unit tests :(

Comment: Primarily that the `dispatch` is actually called. A lot of times I call the action creator without passing to dispatch. Checking that the keyDown action is passed important too, so `expect(dispatch).to.have.been.called` wouldn't be enough I don't think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution might be to memoize `keyDown()` as suggested in another answer (+1). Here's a different approach that attempts to cover all bases...

---

Since `keyDown()` is imported from `actions`, we could [stub](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs)
the function to return
a `dummy` value whenever it gets called with `keyCode`:

```
import * as actions;
keyDown = stub(actions, "keyDown");
keyDown.withArgs(keyCode).returns(dummy);
```

Then, our [unit tests](https://github.com/tony19/mocha-test-demo/blob/1419cdf/test/test-v2.js) would verify `dispatch` was called with the `dummy` that we had previously setup. We know the `dummy` can only be returned by our stubbed `keyDown()`, so this check also verifies that `keyDown()` was called.

```
mapDispatchToProps(dispatch).onKeyDown(createEvent("div", keyCode));
expect(dispatch).to.have.been.calledWith(dummy);
expect(keyDown).to.have.been.calledWithExactly(keyCode);
```

To be thorough, we should add unit tests to confirm that the key event is *not* dispatched when the target is an `<input>`.

```
mapDispatchToProps(dispatch).onKeyDown(createEvent("input", keyCode));
expect(dispatch).to.not.have.been.called;
expect(keyDown).to.not.have.been.called;
```

We should also [test](https://github.com/tony19/mocha-test-demo/blob/1419cdf/test/test-actions.js#L36) `keyDown()` itself in isolation by verifying that the given `dispatch` callback is invoked with the correct key event and key
code:

```
expect(dispatch).to.have.been.calledWith({type: actions.KEYDOWN, key: keyCode});
```

*Links*

- [GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19/mocha-test-demo)
- [100% test coverage](https://travis-ci.org/tony19/mocha-test-demo/jobs/193593403)

Answer (score 3):

As @DarkKnight said (got +1), `keyDown` is returning a new function for every invocation, so the test fails because `keyDown(keyCode)` != `keyDown(keyCode)`.

If you don't want to change your actual implementation of `keyDown`, you can just mock in your tests:

```
import * as actions from "./actions";   

spyOn(actions, 'keyDown');
```

You can see other answers on how it can be done:

- [How to mock the imports of an ES6 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-to-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module)
- [How to mock dependencies for unit tests with ES6 Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323031/how-to-mock-dependencies-for-unit-tests-with-es6-modules?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

`keyDown(keycode)` creates a new function every time, and every function instances are different, the test case fails as expected.

This can be fixed by memorize functions created by `keyDown`:

```
let cacheKeyDown = {};
export const keyDown = key => cacheKeyDown[key] || cacheKeyDown[key] = (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { modifier } = getState().data;
    dispatch({ type: KEYDOWN, key });
    return handle(modifier, key);
};
```

With memorization, `keyDown` calls with same `keycode` return the same function.